# Where is the twentyten_posted_on(); of the index page in a Wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress

I found the  `twentyten_posted_on();` of a **single page** (`in single.php`). But I can't find the one that's included in the index page of my Wordpress blog (the first page you see when you enter a Wordpress blog). I tried to delete the  `twentyten_posted_on();` of `loop.php` but nothing happens.

I checked `index.php` and there's nothing.

Where it is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `loop.php`.  Did you get it in all 3 places?  Lines:

- 65
- 114
- 128

Answer (score 0):

You also need to look in functions.php where the function is actually defined. Can't remember which lines but it's right near the bottom of the file along with twentyten_posted_in()